# Best Way To Check formdata

Tags: javascript, jquery, form-data

I have to upload a file using Ajax.

My issue is i need to use FormData and need to check for browser compatability.

What is the best way to check this?

is it by doing the following:

```
if( window.FormData === undefined )
```

or is there a better more reliable way to check?

Comment: Seems reasonable to me.

Comment: For validation I just go with simple `if` tests and I think a better syntax is `if(typeof window.FormData != "undefined")`. I've read it somewhere and it was saying this is pretty professional.